# How do I convert an array of numpy booleans to python booleans for serialization (e.g. for mongodb)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a numpy array of booleans:

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.zeros(100).astype(np.bool)
x[20] = True # say
```

When I try to insert this (one element per document) as part of an OrderedDict into mongodb, I get the following error:

```
InvalidDocument: cannot encode object: False, of type: <class 'numpy.bool_'>
```

This is a serialization issue I have encountered before for singleton numpy booleans.

**How do I convert the numpy array into an array of python booleans for serialization?**

The following did not work:

```py
y = x.astype(bool)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have just this week come across a solution to this (albeit my own) question from two years ago... Thanks SO!

I am going to invoke the brilliant `numpyencoder` (https://pypi.org/project/numpyencoder) as follows:

```py
# Set up the problem
import numpy as np
x = np.zeros(100).astype(bool) # Note: bool <- np.bool is now deprecated!
x[20] = True

# Let's roll
import json
from numpyencoder import NumpyEncoder
sanitized_json_string = json.dumps(x, cls=NumpyEncoder)

# One could stop there since the payload is now ready to go - but just to confirm:

x_sanitized=json.loads(sanitized_json_string)
print(x_sanitized)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`numpy.ndarray.tolist`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html?highlight=numpy%20ndarray%20tolist#numpy-ndarray-tolist) here.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.zeros(100).astype(np.bool)
y = x.tolist()

print(type(x))
# numpy.ndarray
print(type(x[0]))
# numpy.bool_

print(type(y))
# list
print(type(y[0]))
# bool
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `numpy.asscalar`

```
import numpy as np
x = np.zeros(100).astype(np.bool)
z = [np.asscalar(x_i) for x_i in x]
print(type(z))
```

You can also use `item()` which is a better option since asscalar is depreceted.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.zeros(100).astype(np.bool)
z = [x_i.item() for x_i in x]
print(type(z))
print(z)
```

For a longer list, tolist() is better option.

```
import numpy as np
import time
x = np.zeros(100000).astype(np.bool)
t1 = time.time()
z = [x_i.item() for x_i in x]
t2 = time.time()

print(t2-t1)
t1 = time.time()
z = x.tolist()
t2 = time.time()
print(t2-t1)
```

```
0.0519254207611084
0.0015206336975097656
```